# Can I pass an argument to a function through a keymapping?

Tags: vim

I have a function that takes an argument (num)
I'm wanting a mapping so that I can enter a number beforehand and it gets passed to the function.

e.g If I press `3<leader>i`

I would like the following to happen:
`:call MyFunction(3)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The repeat number is automatically stored in `v:count` and `v:count1`, whichever suits your needs. Also, you have to drop the line range out (`:help c_CTRL-U`):

```
nnoremap <Leader>i :<C-U>call MyFunction(v:count1)<CR>
```

Comment: Jeez, I wish `:help :map` mentioned that somewhere.

Comment: @melpomene Unfortunately, it's only mentioned under `:help v:count`.